# Need to monitor hadoop metrics using java program

Tags: hadoop, monitor

I need to develop an application that monitors hadoop metrics in java, Is there any API's that fetches Hadoop metrics

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop per-se does not offer any system to collect, aggregate and expose the metrics. The metrics are generated by your jobs, is just that no component is using them.

You must install a metrics collection system.  One option is Ambari, see [Ambari Metrics](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Metrics). Another option is the [Cloudera Manager Metrics](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/4.7.0/Cloudera-Manager-Metrics/Cloudera-Manager-Metrics.html). Each has it own API.